# CSS Parent Div Not Resizing to Responsive Image

Tags: html, css, image

I have a parent div that does not resize accordingly with a responsive image width is set to 100%.  The height of the parent div is set to 300px but when the image resizes, the div stays at 300px and leaves a big space between the image and the container content.  I have tried:

```
.bannercon {
  /*height: 300px;*/
    padding: 1em 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

I have created a fiddle to show the problem.

https://jsfiddle.net/volterony/hhyswzw3/

The question is how can I get the image's container div to also resize accordingly so no gap appears between the image and the text?

Cheers

Comment: Your fiddle does not work. there is no code in it.

Comment: sorry. fiddle link updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the fixed height. It will be relative to the image anyway.

Than you have to make the div between the image und `".bannercon"` div position relative so it also has the height of the image.

so remove

```
#header-fade-0 {
  position: absolute;
}
```

and alter .bannercon css rule like this

```
.bannercon {
  padding:1em 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Here's an updated fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/hhyswzw3/8/

Answer (score 0):

Your div size can't be auto resized if you define height to `300px`,try to change `div´s` CSS to

```
div {
    min-height: 300px;
}
```